# Hoverfly simulationMode conflicts with Spring Cloud Config Server in unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot

I'm using hoverfly in my spring boot project's unit test.

## The background

The spring boot project will grab its config (connection timeout etc.) from spring cloud config server.
To test whether my timeout configs work, I write a unit test, and expect the hoverfly can return with a long delay , then my customized restTemplate can throw timeout error instead of wait.
The unit test looks lilke this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestApplication.class)
@FixMethodOrder(value = MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class CustomRestTemplateTest {

@Autowired
private RestTemplate customRestTemplate;

@ClassRule
public static HoverflyRule hoverflyRule = HoverflyRule.inSimulationMode(SimulationSource.dsl(
            service("www.test.com")
            .get("/")
            .willReturn(success(HttpBodyConverter.json("{}")).withDelay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
    ));

@Test
public void connectionTimeoutTest() {
     customRestTemplate.getForObject("www.test.com", Object.class);
}
}
```

## The issue

As I mentioned in section `The background`, when my spring boot project starts, it will grab configs from spring cloud config server, but Hoverfly captured that request and try to find the corresponding record, of course it can't , because I only defined the records for my unit test(e.g. www.test.com), so it throws error:

```
{"destination":"172.16.2.84:8888","error":"No match found","key":"a7ac72c9bcc3dc2b76bf0877d98f9e3a","level":"warning","method":"GET","msg":"Failed to find matching request template from template store","path":"************","query":"","time":"2017-03-08T20:55:28+08:00"}
```

How could I fix this? I want use hoverfly, can I set some config and exclude config server's url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hoverfly's developer Tommy responded me in their [email list](https://groups.google.com/a/specto.io/forum/#!topic/hoverfly/XcXAFHO3lCE)

It's a known issue: https://github.com/SpectoLabs/hoverfly-java/issues/19

---

## Update

This has been fixed by Tommy Situ, and the code fix will be release in ***v0.4.3***